# problem on finding norm

Tags: functional-analysis

let $f$: $l^2$ $\to$ $\Bbb R$ be defined by $$ f(x_1,x_2,x_3,......) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^\frac{n}{2}}   \  \forall x=(x_1,x_2,....) \in l^2$$

then, what is the value of $\left\lVert f\right\rVert$ ??

I am getting $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2-1}$ which is wrong...correct answer is $1$...can anyone help me in proceeding....

thanks a lot.....

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x_1,x_2,...)|^2&=&\left|\frac{x_1^2}{2}+\frac{x_2^2}{2^2}+...+\frac{x_n^2}{2^n}+...\right|\\
&\le&\frac{1}{2}(|x_1^2|+|x_2^2|+|x_3^2|+...)\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2
\end{eqnarray}$

Thus $\|f\|\le\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$

Now, set $x=(1,0,0,...)$  we have $\|x\|=1$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Therefore $\|f\|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

But, if you think in $\ell^2$ as vectors indexed from $\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}$, then $f(x_0,x_1,x_2...)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x_n}{2^{n/2}}$ give us a functional with norm 1. The proof is the same.

Comment: but the answer is given to be 1

Comment: But the answer should be...